# using BottomCount() to find 25th percentile median in SSAS

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I'm trying to find the Median, 25th percentile, and 75th percentile as a calculation in my cube. The values I'm evaluating are non-summable because they represent ages of people, so I'm using the following function to find the median:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Set Median] AS MEDIAN(
    [Dimension].[Key Attribute].MEMBERS
    ,Measures.[Non-summable Measure]
)
```

The dimension key and the fact table key have a 1-1 relationship, so the key members as a set allow me to find the median across all the returned records without any summing. I've successfully found the 75th percentile using the following function combination:

```
MEMBER Measures.[75th Percentile] AS MEDIAN(
    TOPCOUNT(
        [Dimension].[Key Attribute].MEMBERS
        ,Measures.[Fact Table Record Count] / 2
        ,Measures.[Non-summable Measure]
    )
    ,Measures.[Non-summable Measure]
)
```

Since TopCount sorts the set in descending order, I'm able to find the 75th Percentile by finding the median of the top half of the records. Based on this logic, I'm trying to find the 25th Percentile by using the BottomCount function the same way since it sorts the set in ascending order. However, I'm only getting NULL back in my query for the 25th Percentile calculation. Here is the function combination and my end query:

```
MEMBER Measures.[75th Percentile] AS MEDIAN(
    BOTTOMCOUNT(
        [Dimension].[Key Attribute].MEMBERS
        ,Measures.[Fact Table Record Count] / 2
        ,Measures.[Non-summable Measure]
    )
    ,Measures.[Non-summable Measure]
)

SELECT
    {
        Measures.[Set Median]
        ,Measures.[25th Percentile]
        ,Measures.[75th Percentile]
    } ON 0
    ,[Date Dimension].[Calendar Hierarchy].Year.&[2011]:[Date Dimension].[Calendar Hierarchy].Year.&[2014] ON 1
FROM [Cube]
WHERE
    [Age Dimension].[Age in Years Hierarchy].[Age Year].&[0]:[Age Dimension].[Age in Years Hierarchy].[Age Year].&[5]
```

I don't understand why I'm getting NULLs back for the 25th Percentile using the Median and BottomCount functions when I'm not having trouble with the opposite situation for the 75th Percentile using the Median and TopCount functions. I've checked my data set in the SQL database and none of my measure values are NULL. If anyone has a better understanding of the BottomCount function, I appreciate any clear explanation or an alternate way to help me find the correct 25th Percentile in MDX. Thanks!

Comment: First, there is more than one type of percentile available.  Have you identified which one you want?  Next, why would the fact that a number represents an age make them non-summable?

Comment: By percentile, I mean the median-like value found at that percentage point of the population. For example, the normal median is the 50th percentile. About the age being non-summable, I wouldn't use the sum of the age of 3,000 people in a report because it wouldn't be useful, but the median age might be useful as well as median values at various percentile points. Percentile is the term our statistician uses, so hopefully I'm using it correctly here.

Comment: I attempted something similar a few years back and gave up - MDX is so obscure.  I prefer SQL solutions e.g. http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/sql-server-2012-solutions-median-calculation (see Solution 2 or Solution 3 if you have SQL 2012+).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **[Dimension].[Key Attribute].MEMBERS**
it seems like this should work - **NONEMPTY(LEAVES([Dimension]))**

but I tried it and it just hangs, never returns results, at least I didn't have the patience to wait more than 10 minutes

So I used this instead, and it worked fine
**FILTER({LEAVES([Dimension])}, Measures.[Non-summable Measure]> 0)**

Here is my full query which returns the correct 25th percentile

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[P25] AS  
MEDIAN( BOTTOMCOUNT(
            FILTER({LEAVES([Dimension])}, Measures.CalculatedRate > 0)
            ,[Measures].[Dimension Member Distinct Count] /2 
            ,Measures.[CalculatedRate]
        )
        ,[CalculatedRate]
    )
SELECT
{Region.MEMBERS} ON ROWS,
{[Measures].[P25]} ON COLUMNS
FROM
[Cube]
where
    ( <where clause> )
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the `Measures.[Set Median]` you created in the definitions of the 25th and 75th percentile by putting it into a `FILTER` clause such that the definition for 25th was something like:

```
MEDIAN(
    FILTER(
        [Dimension].[Key Attribute].MEMBERS, 
        Measures.[Non Summable Measure] < Measures.[Set Median]
    ),
    Measures.[Non Summable Measure]
)
```

The definition for the 75th would be similar but using the greater than sign. There are some boundary issues here, so you might want <= or >=.

Warning: This query has been nowhere near an MDX parser!

Answer (score 0):

Beware that there is no standard definition of percentile nor for quartiles (Q1 and Q3 which correspond to P25 and P75). This query implements one definition of percentile, modify it to match the definition you want to use.

Lets take a set and order it according to a measure..

```
With
  set CUSTOMERS as Order( [Customers].Children), [Measures].[Sales], ASC )
```

We calculate the Rank of each set item and the total count of elements in the set.

```
  member [Measures].[Rank] as Rank( [Customers].CurrentMember, CUSTOMERS)
  member [Measures].[Count] as Count( CUSTOMERS )
```

Dividing the first by the second we get (one definition of) the percentile.

```
  member [Measures].[Percentile] as [Measures].[Rank] / [Measures].[Count] * 100
```

To get the 25th percentile, get the first item that has a percentile value of at least 25

```
select 
  Head( Filter( CUSTOMERS, [Measures].[Percentile] > 25) ,1) on Rows,
  { [Measures].[Sales], [Measures].[Rank], [Measures].[Count], [Measures].[Percentile]  } on columns
from [MyCube]
```

The [Measures].[Sales] value of this item is the percentile.